# get image from ashx Url using Watin

Tags: url, watin, ashx

I wanna get the image from ashx url using watin can anybody tell me how to get image using watin api

http://www.nmlsconsumeraccess.org/EntityDetails.aspx/COMPANY/76986
this is the link
when you open this link there is the Captchas image which url is ashx.

code

```
IE ie = new IE();
ie.GoTo("http://www.nmlsconsumeraccess.org/EntityDetails.aspx/COMPANY/76986");
ie.WaitForComplete();

Image img = ie.Image(Find.ById("turingImage"));

img. ????
```

I wanna save the Captchas image

Answer (score 0):

Using the ie developer toobar find you the property that you need, off the top of my head it would be img.src or img.url

The whole point of a Captcha though is to stop automation, so you should get your developers to deploy a test version that does not have it enabled.